# Adding Elemental to GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt-elemental

I have a GWT maven multi module project. It runs fine with `mvn gwt:run` - but when I add in `<inherits name='elemental.Elemental'/>` to the gwt.xml file, I get the error below.

Key point appears to be something in JSNI breaking on traversal?

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 13, Size: 13 
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604) 
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382) 
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader$DispatchClassInfoOracle.getClassInfoByDispId(CompilingClassLoader.java:120) 
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.getClassInfoByDispId(CompilingClassLoader.java:1014) 
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.Jsni$JsSourceGenWithJsniIdentFixup.visit(Jsni.java:177)
```

I tried debugging it but I can't seem to track down anything. Any ideas?

> 00:00:19.630 [ERROR] Unable to load module entry point class
>   com.rc.gloopsh.admin.AdminEntryPoint (see associated exception for
>   details) com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected
>   error during visit.   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.translateException(JsVisitor.java:483)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:470)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:893)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsReturn.traverse(JsReturn.java:49)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)  at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.printJsBlock(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:1032)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsSourceGenerationVisitor.visit(JsSourceGenerationVisitor.java:59)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsBlock.traverse(JsBlock.java:47)  at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)  at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.Jsni.generateJavaScriptForHostedMode(Jsni.java:253)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.Jsni.getJavaScriptForHostedMode(Jsni.java:241)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.createNativeMethods(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:52)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.injectJsniMethods(CompilingClassLoader.java:1380)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.findClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1151)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.loadClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1196)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.appendChild(DOM.java:66)   at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Hyperlink.(Hyperlink.java:191)    at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Hyperlink.(Hyperlink.java:90)     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Hyperlink.(Hyperlink.java:181)    at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Hyperlink.(Hyperlink.java:140)    at
>   com.rc.gloopsh.resources.GloopshNav.addNav(GloopshNav.java:34)    at
>   com.rc.gloopsh.admin.AdminEntryPoint.onModuleLoad(AdminEntryPoint.java:29)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:406)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 13, Size: 13  at
>   java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader$DispatchClassInfoOracle.getClassInfoByDispId(CompilingClassLoader.java:120)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.getClassInfoByDispId(CompilingClassLoader.java:1014)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.Jsni$JsSourceGenWithJsniIdentFixup.visit(Jsni.java:177)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsInvocation.traverse(JsInvocation.java:69)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:893)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsReturn.traverse(JsReturn.java:49)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)  at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.printJsBlock(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:1032)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsSourceGenerationVisitor.visit(JsSourceGenerationVisitor.java:59)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsBlock.traverse(JsBlock.java:47)  at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)  at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.Jsni.generateJavaScriptForHostedMode(Jsni.java:253)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.Jsni.getJavaScriptForHostedMode(Jsni.java:241)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.createNativeMethods(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:52)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.injectJsniMethods(CompilingClassLoader.java:1380)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.findClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1151)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.loadClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1196)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.appendChild(DOM.java:66)   at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Hyperlink.(Hyperlink.java:191)    at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Hyperlink.(Hyperlink.java:90)     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Hyperlink.(Hyperlink.java:181)    at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Hyperlink.(Hyperlink.java:140)    at
>   com.rc.gloopsh.resources.GloopshNav.addNav(GloopshNav.java:34)    at
>   com.rc.gloopsh.admin.AdminEntryPoint.onModuleLoad(AdminEntryPoint.java:29)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:406)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7481); for now you'll have to use [SuperDevMode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html) if you use Elemental.

Answer (score 0):

Seem there is something in `elemental.Elemental` which can not be compiled by the GWTJS compiler. Since [Elemental is experimental](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/elemental/STOP.EXPERIMENTAL) things like this can happen...

Comment: the SVN is stale, GWT has moved to Git at https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt; that said, Element still is experimental, but this specific issue is due to DevMode more than Elemental.